# Add <script> and run in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need put  into html page and run it. I tried this, but without success.

```
var div = document.createElement("script");
div.setAttribute('src', 'http://ad.leadboltmobile.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=947870953');
document.body.appendChild(div);
alert(div.innerHTML);
eval(div.innerHTML);`
```

Comment: `eval` doesn’t work on HTML.  Take that out. Also, why are you naming a script element `div`?

Comment: that url doesnt return any javascript, is it just an example url?

Comment: naming DIV is only mistake, o tried lot of solutions... And url return javascript only on mobile devicces.

Answer (score 0):

How script open and close tags look in HTML5

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var div = document.createElement("script");
     div.setAttribute('src', 'http://ad.leadboltmobile.net/show_app_ad.js?    section_id=947870953');
     document.body.appendChild(div);
     alert(div.innerHTML);
     eval(div.innerHTML);
    </script>
```